# How to get image from node-express and view the image in Angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I try to get an image from backend and view in my angular app and fail.

My server route:

```
app.get("/signature/:id", (req,res) => {
  res.send("./dest/signature.png");
})
```

ClientService:

```
  image() {
    return this.http.request('GET', this.baseUrl + '/signature/' + '1', {responseType: 'blob'}).toPromise();
  }
```

Component

```
 ngOnInit(){
 this.service.image().then((image) => {
      const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(image);
      this.image = imageURL;
    });
}
```

my Error on browser:

```
core.js:6629 WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value blob:http://localhost:4200/406c69e3-93b6-4c00-8ec8-b43c7f266737 (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

unsafe:blob:http://localhost:4200/406c69e3-93b6-4c00-8ec8-b43c7f266737:1 GET unsafe:blob:http://localhost:4200/406c69e3-93b6-4c00-8ec8-b43c7f266737 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pipe to bypass this issue.

```
ng g pipe safeHtml
```

pipe.ts:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

In your template, simply write

```
<img [src]="image | safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent work with change in the server to "sendfile"

Answer (score 1):

The correct API is: sendFile

```
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html
```

Alternate ways:

1. You can return a stream of image.
2. You can put your images at some place exposed to public. And can just return URL of that image.

Comment: Thanks man i change it to "sendfile" and it work together with the safe pipe in angular

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an image URL based on some Image object. Just you can get the full path URL of image from Back-end and simply display it in your Angular App using `img` tag.

```
 <img [src]="{{res.img_url}}" alt="image-txt">
```